# How to dispalay facebook ads based on product category?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

I have an online shop in which I am selling multiple products eg tv, radio, shoes, computer, something like this here: [online shop](https://mediamarkt.pl/)

I want to track products abandoned in a cart, meaning the user decided not to buy a certain product.

Now I am able to display ads but general ads, not ads for the specific product.

In the image below u can see the structure.

[image]

if the user bought a product we don't show anything, only if the user abandoned the cart.

Assume user wanted to buy a Jordan added this product to the cart but at last, decide not to buy, so I want to display  Air Jordan promo video to this user in facebook.

I have a few questions:

```
1. Is it possible to achieve what I want?.

2. Do I need a rest API for this to work ?.
```

In short How to display facebook ads based on product category eg shoes, electronics etc?

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: First of all you’d need to specify, _where_ and _when_ you determine that a user has abandoned their cart.

Comment: @misorude that is simple part , facebook pixel provide that mechanism on settings, the problem is displaying ads for the specific product left in the cart, its easy to just display a general user reminder adds

Comment: Then your question is rather about _configuration_ on the Facebook side of things, and as a non-programming question it is rather off-topic here to begin with. // https://uhurunetwork.com/cart-abandonment/ goes into a similar direction, but only talks about creating a target audience based on overall cart abandonment. I guess you would have to create a specific custom audience for each single product then, so that you can then target an ad containing that product to them …

Comment: @misorude That is I why I added a question If I need to create a rest API to achieve what I want (meaning programmatically) most of the tutorials talk about creating a target audience based on overall cart abandonment. not on a single product

Comment: I don’t see what creating your own(?) API could possibly achieve here? Especially since you say, determining abandonment of cart is completely in Facebook’s hands to begin with.

Comment: I think can be achieved but will be a huge job to get it done using facebook API, I need to keep googling if there is a solution to target a single product